# I need a simple java example of processing a JSON response via HTTP for Android App?

Tags: android, json

I am writing a simple Android app and have a database that will send back information into the app. I am new to Android and am looking for a simple example that demonstrates how the Android App can process a JSON response received from a HTTP request.

I need to see what classes are used for Android apps to process a HTTP response. A reference to a good tutorial, or if you're keen, write a very basic method to do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to: [JSON Parsing in android](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) or [Android as a RESTful Client](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/).

Also read [Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading) to be sure that your application is not "hanging" if content retrieval takes time.

Comment: Those 2 links were really helpful. Seems to cover the topic enough for me. So you get the "correcta-mundo". Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a [tutorial](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html) for the exact opposite case (to send a JSON request). However from that you will be able to derive for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for submitting your tutorial. I'll have a look at it and try it out. I need to support XML and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [small library project (stepsdk)](https://github.com/stepsdk/android-stepsdk) and [demo here](https://github.com/stepsdk/android-demo/blob/master/src/com/stepsdk/demo/HomeActivity.java), on making a GET request and process the json here.

It is as simple as follows:

```
new APIRequest(new APIManager(this), SERVER_URL+"/method", APIRequest.GET)
  .addParam('param', 'value')
  .start(new JSONRequestHandler(){
      @Override
      public void after() {
        JSONObject json = getResponse();
        // use json
      }
  });
```

hope it helps.