# Any java examples for OpenExchangeRates.org

Tags: java, android

[openexchangerates.org](http://openexchangerates.org) doesn't have any Java examples for fetching the rates that I could find. There is a [place holder](http://openexchangerates.org/documentation#example-java) but it's empty.  I would very much like to see some example code which could be used in an android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [I need a simple java example of processing a JSON response via HTTP for Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581816/i-need-a-simple-java-example-of-processing-a-json-response-via-http-for-android)

There seems to be nothing special with openexchangerates. Just get the JSON data with HTTP GET and create an object out of it. You can create a class for the exchange rate and use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to instantiate the object.

Comment: Thanks. :) This is about what I can up with myself. I was just wondering if anyone had an implementation that is a part of their android application.